# issue with page redirection when signing out PHP

Tags: php

ill show my folders first:

i have a "cards" and "pages" folder. both have a "header.php" where a signout button is located and a "signout.php" to end the user session. in my "header.php" the signout button works in the "pages" folder but not in my "cards" (im getting a 404 page not found)

both header.php files on both folders have the same href:

```
<a href="signout" class="small color-orange spacer-left">SIGN OUT</a>
```

"signout.php" of the pages folder (works)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: main'); die();
?>
```

"signout.php" of the cards folder (404 Not Found)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: register'); die();
?>
```

- would just like to point out that the Locations exist

[image: error]

just suprised by the error since both folders have the exact same code

Comment: The redirection is not the same

Comment: Do you have any explicit rewriting in place to make `signout` refer to the `signout.php` script? Or are you purely reyling on the effects of MultiViews being enabled for this to work?

Comment: what are MultiViews?

Comment: apologies i was just given this sign out issue, the codes are not mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the cards folder, have you tried adding ../signout?